# NameError: name 'url_data' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to use the below code to search for a keyword in a given URL (internal website at work) and I keep getting the error. It works fine on public site.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import urllib.request

class CustomHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.tag_flag = False
        self.tag_line_num = 0
        self.tag_string = 'temporary_tag'

    def initiate_vars(self, tag_string):
        self.tag_string = tag_string

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        #if tag == 'tag_to_search_for':
        if tag == self.tag_string:
            self.tag_flag = True
            self.tag_line_num = self.getpos()


if __name__== '__main__':
    #simple_str = 'string_to_search_for'
    simple_str = 'Host Status'

    my_url = 'TEST_URL'

    parser_obj = CustomHTMLParser()

    #parser_obj.initiate_vars('tag_to_search_for')
    parser_obj.initiate_vars('script')

    #html_file = open('location_of_html_file//file.html')
    my_request = urllib.request.Request(my_url)

    try:
        url_data = urllib.request.urlopen(my_request)
    except:
        print("There was some error opening the URL")

    html_str = url_data.read().decode('utf8')
    #html_str = html_file.read()

    #print (html_str)

    html_search_result = html_str.lower().find(simple_str.lower())
    if html_search_result != -1:
        print ('The word {} was found'.format(simple_str))
    else:
        print ('The word {} was not found'.format(simple_str))

    parser_obj.feed(html_str)

    if parser_obj.tag_flag:
        print ('Tag {0} was found at position {1}'.format(parser_obj.tag_string, parser_obj.tag_line_num))
    else:
        print ('Tag {} was not found'.format(parser_obj.tag_string))
```

but I keep  getting the error

```
There was some error opening the URL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\TEMP\parse.py", line 40, in <module>
    html_str = url_data.read().decode('utf8')
NameError: name 'url_data' is not defined
```

I believe I already tried using urllib2, using python v3.7

Not sure what to do. Is it worth trying user_agent?

EDIT1: I have now tried the below

```
>>> import urllib
>>> url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://concernedURL.com')
```

and I am getting this error "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized". Should I be using the headers I have from my browser as well as SSL certs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you get an error in the `try`-block, and that leaves the `url_data` variable undefined:

```
try:
    # if this errors, no url_data will exist
    url_data = urllib.request.urlopen(my_request)
except:
    # really bad to catch all exceptions!
    print("There was some error opening the URL")

html_str = url_data.read().decode('utf8')
```

You should probably just remove the `try-except`, or handle the error better. It's almost never advicable to use the bare `except` without a specific error since it can create all kinds of problems.

In this case your program should probably just stop running if you cannot open the requested url, since it really doesn't make any sense to try to operate on the url's data if the opening failed in the first place.

Comment: Why not put `html_str = url_data.read().decode('utf8')` inside the `try` block?

Comment: @glhr Because then the next line needs that to be defined. This program just cannot handle the error that the url request doesn't work, thus it's pointless to try to handle it.